# How can my Pause display work properly in Pygame?

Tags: python, pygame, pause

So my pause display keeps returning after I click on the button which continues everything.

This is included in the code:
"def paused():
global pause
clock = pygame.time.Clock()"

```
while pause:

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            exit()

    screen.fill(0)
    screen.blit(intropic, (0, 0))

    mouse = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
    click = pygame.mouse.get_pressed()

    # print(mouse)

    if 270 + 120 > mouse[0] > 270 and 590 + 50 > mouse[1] > 590:
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, (0, 0, 0), (268, 588, 124, 54))
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, (0, 255, 0), (270, 590, 120, 50))
        if click[0] == 1:
            pause = False

    else:
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, (0, 0, 0), (268, 588, 124, 54))
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, (100, 255, 100), (270, 590, 120, 50))

    if 770 + 150 > mouse[0] > 770 and 590 + 50 > mouse[1] > 590:
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, (0, 0, 0), (768, 588, 154, 54))
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, (255, 0, 0), (770, 590, 150, 50))
        if click[0] == 1:
            pygame.quit()
            exit()

    else:
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, (0, 0, 0), (768, 588, 154, 54))
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, (255, 100, 100), (770, 590, 150, 50))

    healthfont = pygame.font.Font(None, 40)
    start = healthfont.render("Weiter", True, (0, 0, 0))
    textRect1 = start.get_rect()
    textRect1.topright = [370, 603]
    screen.blit(start, textRect1)

    healthfont = pygame.font.Font(None, 40)
    end = healthfont.render("Beenden", True, (0, 0, 0))
    textRect1 = end.get_rect()
    textRect1.topright = [900, 603]
    screen.blit(end, textRect1)

    pausefont = pygame.font.Font(None, 80)
    pausetxt = pausefont.render("Pause", True, (0, 0, 0))
    textRect1 = pausetxt.get_rect()
    textRect1.center = [800, 300]
    screen.blit(pausetxt, textRect1)
    pygame.display.flip()
```

This is the code if you press P:

```
    if keys[4]:
        pause = True
        paused()
```

There is also a global pause = False

any help is much appreciated

Comment: Please consider using something like `butt_rect = pygame.Rect( 768, 588, 154, 54 )` to store these rectangles, then you can use `butt_rect.collidepoint( pygame.mouse.get_pos() )`.  This saves your main loop from being peppered with numbers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Being paused or not paused, it's just a boolean.  Your program must decide what that means.

Perhaps it means that the screen is not updated, and perhaps input-handling is different.

Below is a re-working of your code where if the paused flag `global_paused` ever gets set, the screen stops painting everything except a "*** PAUSED ***" banner.

Note the use of `pyagme.Rect` to store rectangles, constants for colours, an simpler testing of collisions.  Fonts only need to be loaded once, so these have been moved outside the main loop.

```
global_paused = False

BLACK    = (0, 0, 0)
RED      = (0, 255, 0)
GREENISH = (100, 255, 100)

area1 = pygame.Rect( 268, 588, 124, 54 )
area2 = pygame.Rect( 270, 590, 120, 50 )

area3 = pygame.Rect(768, 588, 154, 54)
area4 = pygame.Rect(770, 590, 150, 50)

healthfont = pygame.font.Font(None, 40)
start = healthfont.render("Weiter", True, BLACK )
textRect1 = start.get_rect()
textRect1.topright = [370, 603]

healthfont = pygame.font.Font(None, 40)
end = healthfont.render("Beenden", True, BLACK )
textRect1 = end.get_rect()
textRect1.topright = [900, 603]

pausefont = pygame.font.Font(None, 80)
pausetxt = pausefont.render("Pause", True, BLACK )
textRect1 = pausetxt.get_rect()
textRect1.center = [800, 300]

pause_mode = pausefont.render( "*** PAUSED ***", True, RED, BLACK )


clock = pygame.time.Clock()
exiting = False
while not exiting:

    mouse_click = None
    mouse_pos   = pygame.mouse.get_pos()

    # Handle Events
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            exit()
        elif ( event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONUP ):
            mouse_click = pygame.mouse.get_pressed()
            if ( area1.collidepoint( event.pos ) ):
                global_paused = not global_paused
            elif ( area3.collidepoint( event.pos ) ):
                exiting = True
        elif ( event.type == pygame.KEYUP ):
            if ( event.key == pygame.K_p ):
                global_paused = not global_paused

    # draw the screen
    screen.fill( BLACK )
    
    if ( not global_paused ):
        screen.blit(intropic, (0, 0))

        pygame.draw.rect(screen, BLACK, area1 )
        if ( area1.collidepoint( mouse_pos ) ):
            pygame.draw.rect(screen, RED, area2 )
        else:
            pygame.draw.rect(screen, GREENISH, area2 )

        pygame.draw.rect(screen, BLACK, area3 )
            pygame.draw.rect(screen, RED, area4 )
        else:
            pygame.draw.rect(screen, GREENISH, area4 )

        screen.blit(start, textRect1)
        screen.blit(end, textRect1)
        screen.blit(pausetxt, textRect1)
    
    else:
        # everything is paused
        screen.blit( pause_mode, ( 0, 0 ) )
    
    pygame.display.flip()
    clock.tick( 60 )
    
pygame.quit()
```